# Avoid building project in a loop for target/generated-sources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xjc, buildpath

I have got a `Spring-boot` project where I need to have `generated sources` from a `WSDL` location.

My maven build plugin for the WSDL endpoint looks like that:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>0.13.2</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
            <args>
               <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
            </args>
            <locale>DE</locale>
            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
            <generatePackage>com.myCompany.myProject.wsdl.svs</generatePackage>
            <schemas>
               <schema>
                  <url>https://urlToWS.wsdl</url>
               </schema>
            </schemas>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
   </plugins>
</build>
```

The generation of the sources works as expected and are under `target/generated-sources/xjc` of my project:

[image]

**My Problem is, that eclipse (or maven) builds this project every second.** This is really annoying because every other task have to wait for the build.

I know that I am able to remove this folder from the build path. But If I do so I will also remove my sources and my project is in an invalid state.

[image]

**So is there a way to avoid building the project without removing the generated sources from the build path?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***Project > Properties: Builders*** you can (temporary) **disable other project builders than *Java Builder*** (which compiles the Java code) by unchecking them.

Comment: That depends on the deactivated builders, e. g. _Maven Project Builder_ will update the Java build path when editing the `pom.xml` file. If unwanted side effects occur, temporarily activate all builders and clean all projects for a full build.

Comment: I deavtivated Maven Project Builder. Changes in pom.xml can be build manually. If this is all its not a problem for me.

Comment: And if Maven Project Builder is deavtivated, is there a way to build the pom.xml manually without activating the builder again?

Comment: What do you mean with _build the pom.xml manually_? The Maven POM editor and _Run As > Maven ..._ should no be affected by the deactivated Maven project builder.

Comment: yeah, thanks. Was thinking in a wrong direction. Know its clear :-)